# Correct 'type' for startup service

Tags: bash, shell-script, boot, services, startup

I have a LCD panel that is run through a python script, the panel takes in key-press inputs so the script is always listening. I'm trying to create a startup service that would run the script as soon as the machine boots.

From what I've read `Type=simple` would be the most suitable for it but it won't run the script. However `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=true` works. Any ideas as to why?

This is the lcd-panel.service;

```
[Unit]
Description=LCD Panel

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path
ExecStart=/path/start-lcd-panel.sh
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=lcd-panel

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the start-lcd-panel.sh bash script that will run the python script

```
#!/bin/bash
Application=LCD-Panel

cd /path

if ! [ -e "/path2_exist" ] ; then

    #run lcd panel
    sudo /path/run-menu.py lcd &
fi

if (( $(pgrep -f -c 'run-menu.py lcd') >= 1 )); then
    echo "Started LCD display"
fi
```

Comment: "won't run the script" - Do you mean systemd doesnt show the service as active, or that you think it didn't execute because your panel didn't "run" (come on I'm guessing)?

Comment: Did you try `journalctl --unit lcd-panel.service` when you had it set to simple?

Comment: systemd doesn't show it as active and when I try 'ps aux' the 'run-menu.py lcd' won't show up and the LCD panel won't work. It does work with oneshot

Comment: Yes just tried journalctl, I added 'Restart=always' and 'RestartSec=10' for 'Type=simple' so journalctl just shows that it's perpetually restarting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;
I think it comes down to this: For a `simple` service you want your process to sit in the foreground, blocking. And that being the process provided to `ExecStart`

Background

If I read the manpage, I see these standing out to me:

simple: `the service manager consider the unit started immediately after the main service process has been forked off`
along with `It is expected that process configured with ExecStart= is the main of the service` which yours is not, since it executes `run-meny.py`. My interpretation of simple is that you want your process to sit in the foreground, blocking.

oneshot: `the manager will consider the unit up after the main exits` in your case, `start-lcd-panel.sh` is your main process, which will exit after forking `run-menu.py` (you have an ampersand at the end of that line). I'm not sure how the forking of `run-menu.py` will be interpreted, or even if child processes (`run-menu.py`) will die along with the main process.

oneshot: `Note that if this option is used without RemainAfterExit= the service will never enter "active" unit state, but directly transition from "activating" to "deactivating" or "dead" since no process is configured that shall run continuously` Which will explain `systemctl status` results.

Also of interest from the man page: `Also note it is generally not to use idle or oneshot for long-running services.`

**

My suggestion: I think the use of the script is superficial because it switches to /path , which is covered by `WorkingDirectory`. You also have `User=root`, which means the `sudo` in the script is redundant. Not sure what benefit the `echo` at the end has, as you'll see the screen not being on.

Instead: `ExecStart=/path/run-menu.py lcd` along with `simple`.

[Systemd manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html)